# Why can't we loop over `...`?

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Why does the following not work?

```
f = function(...) for (i in ...) print(i)
f(1:3)
# Error in f(1:3) : '...' used in an incorrect context
```

while this work fine

```
f = function(...) for (i in 1:length(...)) print(...[i])
f(1:3)
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 8):

It does not work because the `...` object type is not accessible in interpreted code. You need to capture the object as a list as nongkrong showed:

```
for(i in list(...))
```

Take a look at the R manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot)

Comment: You can also wrap it in `c` such as `c(...)`

Comment: @Remi.b As a sidenote, you can actually access specific elements of `...` as `..1`, `..2`, etc. Not terribly useful for looping, but you will see that used from time to time as a shortcut to get at a specific item.

Comment: @joran - nifty, and this is documented in `?Reserved` for those that are wondering.